# ruby-1.9.3-p125 ssl error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, rvm

I just installed ruby-1.9.3-p125 using RVM.

I can create a basic app

```
rails new my app.
```

but when I try building a new app using the rails starter app here: 
https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan

by running

```
rails new rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan -m https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/master/composer.rb -T
```

it breaks down and gives me the following error:

```
/Users/macuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

It may be worth noting that this worked when using ruby-1.9.2-p290

does any one know how I can fix this?

I'm running osx lion 10.7.4

---

openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.0f 4 Jan 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running osx lion 10.7.4

my openssl version  was OpenSSL 1.0.0f and i needed to update to 1.0.1

I did this by following this guide:

http://railsapps.github.com/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

This was the solution that worked for me:

```
curl -L -O http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1b.tar.gz.asc
curl -L -O http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1b.tar.gz
gpg --verify openssl-1.0.1b.tar.gz.asc
tar xvzf openssl-1.0.1b.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.1b
perl ./Configure shared zlib --prefix=/opt/local darwin64-x86_64-cc
make
make test
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is because of a bug in your version of rubygems.

You can either run

```
gem update --system
```

Or, remove the s from your sources in your gemfile, like so:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

Comment: the first suggestion: 
Latest version currently installed. Aborting.

How do I do the second suggestion in the command line before creating the app?

Comment: The second suggestion should be (one of) the first line(s) in your gemfile (in your application root).

Answer (score 1):

For OSX with Homebrew:

```
brew install curl-ca-bundle
export SSL_CERT_FILE=/usr/local/opt/curl-ca-bundle/share/ca-bundle.crt
```

Add the last line to your `.bashrc`.